# AwsSdkMetrics.setMetricCollector(...) for AWS SDK v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, prometheus, metrics, spring-micrometer

In v1 for Java, one could call `AwsSdkMetrics.setMetricCollector(new MyCustomCollector())` if you wanted SDK client metrics but didn't want to use CloudWatch (we use Prometheus and Grafana). With a custom collector, we could automatically transform any AWS service call in the application to a Prometheus metric without having to wrap each and every call site or client reference in the codebase.

Is there any way to do the equivalent of the old method call in v2 of the Java SDK? If it helps, this is a Spring Boot app using Micrometer.

Comment: Apparently it does not exist in v2 yet.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3311#issuecomment-1194487912